# How to get the contact online status of Skype friends via Applescript

Tags: applescript, skype

is there a way to get the online status of each Skype contact via Applescript?

So far I only managed to get the group of online users. However, I need also the corresponding online status.

Thnaks for your help!

Cheers 
Julian

```
set groupType to send command "GET GROUP " & group & " TYPE" script name "getType"
    if groupType contains "ONLINE" then
        set onlineFriends to send command "GET GROUP " & group & " USERS" script name "getType"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, its quite easy... sometimes it helps to take a break ;-)

```
tell application "Skype"
   set result to send command "GET USER <userName> ONLINESTATUS" script name "getType"
end tell
```

Cheers 
Julian